# How to refer to a class when both simple and fully-qualified names clash

Tags: java, language-specifications

Consider the following pathological example:

```
class Ideone {
  static class ArrayList<T> {
    ArrayList() {
      System.out.println("!!");
    }
  }

  static class java {
    static class util {
      static class ArrayList<T> {
        ArrayList() {
          System.out.println("Here");
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ArrayList<>();
    new java.util.ArrayList<>();
    // Can I refer to the "usual" java.util.ArrayList?
  }
}
```

The two instances created in the constructor are of the nested classes.

But how might I refer to the [`java.util.ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) that we all know and love in the same class? We can't import it, and we can't use the fully-qualified name, as the nested class symbols would be used instead.

What can we do in this case? (Other than the obvious - stop using such wantonly evil names for the nested classes).

Comment: Do you have a reason to believe there's some solution?

Comment: @shmosel not especially. I'm just thinking up bizarre corner cases for imports, whilst working on some Error Prone checks.

Comment: I'd love to see one of the language architects answer this question.

Comment: That problem can't happen if you follow standard [**Java Naming Conventions**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html), i.e. package names in all lowercase, and class names in mixed case. Naming conventions exist for a reason.

Comment: @Andreas I agree; but I am asking about what is permitted by the *language*, not what is used by convention.

Comment: @shmosel in C# there is a solution. You can specify global:: prefix to reference an original Java class. 
I.e. new global::java.util.ArrayList<>();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can no longer directly reference `java.util.ArrayList` if you've done the 2 things you've done:

1. Hide the simple name `ArrayList` with a static nested class in scope.
2. Hide the fully qualified name `java.util.ArrayList` with a class `ArrayList` nested within class `util`, nested within nested class `java`.

You can't even "split" the import in an attempt to use a "partially qualified" import.

```
import java.*;

...

// This doesn't work!
new util.ArrayList<>();
```

You can `import java.*;`, but that is worthless; no classes are defined in the `java` package directly.

However, you can reference the class `java.util.ArrayList` indirectly because it's not `final`.  Outside the scope of the class `Ideone`, declare a subclass with a different name.

```
class AnArrayList<T> extends java.util.ArrayList<T> {}
```

Then you can refer to that class and program to the interface:

```
List<Integer> al = new AnArrayList<>();  // won't print !! or Here
```

Comment: Of course, you could get an *actual* `java.util.ArrayList` by using something like `Stream.of().collect(Collectors.toList())`.

Comment: @AndyTurner That sounds like you should answer your own question.  I looked up the source code for `Collectors.toList`, and it uses `ArrayList::new`, confirming your claim.

Comment: maybe. It's not really an answer to the question I'm intending to ask, which is can you refer to the *type*, not how do you get an instance of the type.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to go out on a limb and say that it's not possible to refer to it from within `Ideone`.  The only solution that I see is to create another class `Idetwo` (which is a nestmate of `Ideone` (i.e. it resides in the same file)) and return a `java.util.ArrayList` from there for use in `Ideone`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Ideone {
    ...
}

class Idetwo {
    static ArrayList<Integer> getList() {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(1);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(3);
        return list;
    }
}
```

And you'd just change your `Ideone`'s main method to something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new Ideone.ArrayList<>();
    new Ideone.java.util.ArrayList<>();
    Idetwo.getList().forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Output:

```
!!
Here
1
2
3
```

**Note**: With this method, importing `java.util.ArrayList` will work fine.  However, if you were to call `List<Integer> list = Idetwo.getList();` inside `Ideone`'s main method, you need to import `java.util.*`, as individual imports will not work (interestingly).

Comment: Nice try, but I said "in the same class", not "in the same *compilation unit*" ;)

Comment: @AndyTurner Darn, missed that ;)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
Class cls = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass("java.util.ArrayList");
List arrayList = cls.newInstance();
```

It's been a long time since I've thought about classloaders, but IIRC `.loadClass()` will preferentially try to load from the most fundamental classloader, and the real `java.util` package should be provided by the bootstrap classloader, which gives it higher precedence than anything you define in your application.

Comment: This should work if you call `loadClass` instead of `findClass`, which is `protected`.

Answer (score 1):

That's why packages start with lower case letters, and types with upper case letters, since the [very first edition of the official code conventions for java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html). I don't think I have ever seen java code break this convention.

But you can refer to the inner type from the outside using it's fully qualified name:

```
com.whatever.bad.project.SomeClass.java.util.ArrayList
```

When you have to refer to the outer type from inside, you can probably change that source file to comply with Java naming guidelines.

Comment: I refer you to the my reply to @Andreas' comment: "I am asking about what is permitted by the language, not what is used by convention".