# (Java) Static member accessed via instance reference with enumerators

Tags: java, variables, enums, static, enumerator

I just started learning Java. IntelliJ is giving me a warning "Static member accessed via instance reference" on line 4. Is it bad, should I fix it, somehow, or should I just ignore it?

Here is my code:

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dog randomDog = new Dog();
        Dog myDog = new Dog(4, "Charlie", new Dog().breed.Labrador);
        System.out.println("Random dog's name is: " + randomDog.name + ", it's age is: " + randomDog.age + " and it's breed is: " + randomDog.breed);
        System.out.println("My dog's name is: " + myDog.name + ", it's age is: " + myDog.age + " and it's breed is: " + myDog.breed);
    }
}
```

and the Dog class:

```
public class Dog {
    int age;
    String name;
    enum breed { Poodle, Shepherd, Labrador }
    breed breed;

    Dog(int age, String name, breed breed) {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
        this.breed = breed;
    }
    Dog() {
        this.age = 0;
        this.name = "Rex";
        this.breed = breed.Labrador;
    }
}
```

Comment: Fix the problem: `Dog.breed.Labrador`. btw, don't call a field the same as a type, it's just confusing. Call the enum `Breed` and the field `breed`. And enum values are, by convention, capitalized.

Comment: @AndyTurner It is actually required to rename the enum, because `Dog.breed.Labrador` fails. It looks like the property shadows the enum in that class.

Comment: Q: Is it bad?  A: It's just a "warning" - everything will still work as expected.  A bigger problem is the naming conflict between "enum breed" and instance variable "breed".  You should consider setting explicit visibility (i.e. "public", "private" or "protected") for ALL members.

Comment: @paulsm4 "everything will still work as expected" that strongly depends on what you expect, of course.

Comment: @Tom interesting, I wonder how you could refer to `breed` from outside the class without renaming it. Maybe it's another of those funny cases that Java can't handle, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50633759/how-to-refer-to-a-class-when-both-simple-and-fully-qualified-names-clash. I guess it depends on context, because `Dog.breed breed = null;` would work, because there it can only be a type.

Comment: @AndyTurner I guess there is no way to do it without fixing the ambiguity. I also found a question with the same issue: [Java Enums and Fields with same name](//stackoverflow.com/q/39917386)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue (which causes others) is that you're hiding the **type** `breed` by also having a **field** of the same name in the same scope.

That's a very rare problem to have, because the naming conventions of Java usually prevent this kind of clash: Types (classes, interfaces, enums, annotations) are usually written in `CamelCase` whereas field names start with a lower case letter (`fieldName`). While this is not technically a "rule" that the compiler enforces, following this makes your code much more readable to others and also avoids the follow-up problem of hiding the type. Also note that constant fields.

I also made two changes that are good ideas but not really related to your issue:

- constant values (i.e. most `static final` fields an enum constants) use `ALL_UPPER` casing, so I also changed your `Breed` values
- I've moved the nested type definition to the top of your `Dog` class so as not to hide it within all the instance fields. This is just to keep those things that logically belong together close to each other.

```
public class Dog {
    enum Breed { POODLE, SHEPHERD, LABRADOR }

    int age;
    String name;
    Breed breed;

    Dog(int age, String name, Breed breed) {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
        this.breed = breed;
    }
    Dog() {
        this.age = 0;
        this.name = "Rex";
        this.breed = Breed.LABRADOR;
    }
}
```

Changing all these names in the main class and replacing the unneded `new Dow().breed` with just `Dog.Breed` produces this working code:

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dog randomDog = new Dog();
        Dog myDog = new Dog(4, "Charlie", Dog.Breed.LABRADOR);
        System.out.println("Random dog's name is: " + randomDog.name + ", it's age is: " + randomDog.age + " and it's breed is: " + randomDog.breed);
        System.out.println("My dog's name is: " + myDog.name + ", it's age is: " + myDog.age + " and it's breed is: " + myDog.breed);
    }
}
```